# How do substances get charged on rubbing them together?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

How do substances get charged on rubbing them together? Also why do only some substances get charged on rubbing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP showed no research efforts at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called [triboelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect):

[It happens because:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect#Cause)

> Although the part 'tribo-' comes from the Greek for "rubbing", τρίβω (τριβή: friction), the two materials only need to come into contact for electrons to be exchanged. After coming into contact, a chemical bond is formed between parts of the two surfaces, called adhesion, and charges move from one material to the other to equalize their electrochemical potential. >This is what creates the net charge imbalance between the objects. When separated, some of the bonded atoms have a tendency to keep extra electrons, and some a tendency to give them away, though the imbalance will be partially destroyed by tunneling or electrical breakdown (usually corona discharge). In addition, some materials may exchange ions of differing mobility, or exchange charged fragments of larger molecules.
>
> The triboelectric effect is related to friction only because they both involve adhesion. However, the effect is greatly enhanced by rubbing the materials together, as they touch and separate many times.